# ¿Como obtengo este formato de fecha en Sql Server 2014?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de dar formato a una fecha en SQLSERVER, mi consulta es

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), FECHA_INI_FALLA, 13) AS FechaFalla
```

y el resultado que obtengo es

```
12 SEP 2017
```

y lo que quiero obtener es

```
12/SEP/2017 O 12-SEP-2017
```

Cabe recalcar que no quiero mostrar la hora, minutos y segundos

¿Que debo cambiar para poder obtener ese formato?

Comment: ¿Que versión de SQL Server usas?

Comment: Uso Sql Server 2014

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A partir de SQL Server **2000**:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), GETDATE(), 13), ' ', '/')
```

A partir de SQL Server **2012**:

```
SELECT FORMAT( GETDATE(), 'dd/MMM/yyyy', 'en-US' )
```

Obtendrás:

> 12/Sep/2017

[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/GTC42960)

Para tu caso:

```
SELECT FORMAT(FECHA_INI_FALLA, 'dd/MMM/yyyy', 'en-US' )
```

---

**Referencia:**

- [FORMAT (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql)

Comment: Voto por esta porque me parece que es la mas practica.

Comment: @LuisFernando edite para versiones anteriores. :)

Answer (score 3):

Usa:

**Modificacion de acuerdo a la edicion de la pregunta del OP sobre no mostrar tiempo en la fecha:**

```
SELECT replace(CONVERT(nvarchar,  Convert(Date, FECHA_INI_FALLA), 13), ' ', '/')
```

ó

```
SELECT replace(CONVERT(nvarchar,  Convert(Date, FECHA_INI_FALLA), 13), ' ', '-')
```

> Gracias a Davilo por la sugerencia de limitacion de informacion usando
>   varchar la cual no realiza un doble cast:

```
SELECT replace(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), GETDATE(), 13), ' ', '/')
SELECT replace(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), GETDATE(), 13), ' ', '-')
```

Saludos

Comment: funciona, pero me salen las horas, minutos y segundos. ¿Como hago para no mostrarlos?

Comment: @LuisFernando he actualizado la respuesta de acuerdo a la actualizacion de tu pregunta. Saludos

Comment: @JesusRodríguez para que no salga más información puedes limitarla cambiando el `nvarchar` a `varchar(11)`. Por ejemplo: `SELECT replace(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),  GETDATE(), 13), ' ', '/')`.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza `Convert`, con formato 106, que ya omite información de horas, minutos, etc.

Luego, reemplaza los espacios por `'-'` o `'/'`, según prefieras:

```
select replace(convert(varchar, FECHA_INI_FALLA, 106), ' ', '-')
```

Te dará el resultado buscado.

Answer (score -1):

Deberías usar:

`SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), FECHA_INI_FALLA, 103) AS FechaFalla`

Dado que el parámetro **103** es el formato Británico/Francés: **dd/mm/yyyy**

Para mas detalle, ver: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

Saludos!

Comment: No muestra el formato que quiero, pero gracias.